# Allow login attempt where role = x or role = y

Tags: php, laravel-5, laravel-5.4

I know it's possible to add a `where` query to the attempt method by passing an array to it. But what about a login form where all users having a specific role are allowed to log in?

Trying all values results a lot of querys, so is there a more elegant want to check if the user is allowed to log in?

```
/**
 * Attempt to log the user into the application.
 *
 * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request $request
 * @return bool
 */
protected function attemptLogin(Request $request)
{
    $values = ['admin', 'distributor']; //all roles that are allowed
    foreach ($values as $value) {
        if ($this->guard()->attempt(array_merge($this->credentials($request), ['role' => $value]), $request->has('remember'))) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: @AlonEitan updated my question

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to login the user manually.

```
protected function attemptLogin(Request $request)
{
    $values = ['admin', 'distributor']; //all roles that are
    $user = App\User::where(array_except($this->credentials($request), 'password'))->whereIn('role', $values)->first();
    if($user) {
        $this->guard()->login($user, $request->has('remember'));
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: This won't work because I can't compare the password in a `where clause`...

Comment: @mimo ah sorry yes, I forgot about that, I'll update my answer

Answer (score 0):

With yazfields help I found a good solution:

```
/**
 * Attempt to log the user into the application.
 *
 * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request $request
 * @return bool
 */
protected function attemptLogin(Request $request)
{
    $query = User::query();
    $query->where($this->username(), $request->get($this->username()));
    $user = $query->whereIn('role', $this->allowedRoles)->first();
    if ($user) {
        return $this->guard()->attempt(
            $this->credentials($request), $request->has('remember')
        );
    }
    return false;
}
```

First you try to get the user by his email address (or username) and filter him with the roles. If you have a match you make a second try to try to login the user. In this case you only expand the `attemptLogin` from Laravel and have a maximum of 2 queries for a login attempt.

Comment: Why would you attempt to login again? just login the user

Comment: @yazfield I want to check if the user is allowed to login. There a several entry points to the system and to some of them need a minimum of privileges.